# what should be chosen as the alternative hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference

I want to test a claim that the population probability is at least 0.9 and Im confused about how I should set my alternative hypothesis.
Should it be H0 : p=0.9 vs H1: p<0.9 or H0: p=0.9 vs H1: p>0.9 ?

Comment: The null incorporates the "state of the art", the claim or the "discovery" typically goes into the alternative. Thus try asking yourself what is the implication if you accept the chosen $H_1$.

Comment: The reason why Im confused is because my claim contains equality. So if I try to put the claim in the alternative, which would be H0:p=0.9 H1:p>0.9, then my claim exists in both null, and alternative so that it cannot be fully disproved whether or not H0 is rejected. Should I also go for the typical method of putting claim into the alternative in this case too?

Comment: Your choice is between a conclusion of the type: "The test [rejected/did not reject] the null hypothesis that the population probability is at least $0.9$ at the $\alpha$ significance level" or "The test [rejected/did not reject] the null hypothesis that the population probability is at most $0.9$ at the $\alpha$ significance level". Without a huge sample size, a test usually cannot distinguish between a critical value of $0.8999$ and $0.9$ and $0.9001$, so equality goes into the null hypothesis. If you do not know which is the baseline understanding then you might use a confidence interval.

Answer (score 0):

X claims: "The probability $p$ is at least 0.9". If you test $H_0:\ p\ge 0.9$ against the alternative $p<0.9$, it means that you will reject X's claim if there is clear evidence against it. For example, if you observe relative frequency $\hat p=0.87$, X's claim will not be rejected, as the result is compatible with $p=0.9$ despite estimating below it, unless the sample size is very large (in which case even a small deviation from the $H_0$ will come out significant).

If you test $H_0:\ p\le 0.9$ against $p>0.9$, you demand significant "proof" that $p$ cannot be 0.9 or smaller. With $\hat p=0.87$ you won't reject $H_0$ and therefore can't say you have evidence that $p>0.9$. In fact this (rather obviously) doesn't even give you evidence for $p\ge 0.9$, and neither does, say, $\hat p=0.92$ in case your sample size is not very large.

Chances are in the given situation you want the first option, however you need to think through the consequences and the background of the situation. Do you want to let X get away with their claim if the evidence isn't clearly against it, or do you actually demand that X "statistically proves" their claim, excluding the possibility that $p<0.9$ with small error probability?

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote can be interpreted in multiple ways, so the answer depends on your research question. Example:

If you have an old medicine that gives at least 90% of people adverse effects, and you want to show that your new medicine is better, then you should test H0 p=0.9 vs one sided H1 p<0.9

If you have and old medicine that treats 90% of people, and you want to show that your new medicine is better than that, then you should test H0 p=0.9 vs one sided H1 p>0.9